# Can I visit Guatemala or Honduras with an Italian residence permit?

Tags: visas, residence-permits

I am a non-EU citizen with a valid Italian residence permit (not PR). Also, I have a valid Schengen visa. Am I able to travel to Guatemala and Honduras without obtaining their visas?

Comment: What country are you citizen of?

Answer (score 5):

While certain citizens ARE exempt from the CA4 visa requirement when holding US, CA, or Schengen visas/residence permits there are select countries whose citizens need a visa whether or not they hold one of those other visas. The source Nicolas used is unclear. So I put it to the test.

Using [IATA Travel Centre](https://iatatravelcentre.com) I input a couple of countries who are exempt with US/Canada/Schengen visas (Azerbaijan and Venezuela) and a couple who cannot use the exemption (Afghanistan and Yemen) as being holders of an Italian(Schengen Member State) residence permits. Timatic confirmed that the list of countries whose citizens cannot use US/Canada/Schengen visa, also cannot enter visa free if they hold Schengen Residence permits.

**Hypothetical direct travel from Italy to El Salvador**:

Scenario 1: Azerbaijan Passport + Italian Residence Permit
[image: Azerbaijan+IT_RP]

Scenario 2: Venezuelan Passport + Italian Residence Permit
[image: VEN+IT_RP]

Scenario 3: Afghanistan Passport + Italian Residence Permit
[image: AfghanITRP]

Scenario 4: Yemen Passport + Italian Residence Permit
[image: YEM+IT_RP]

**In Summary**:
Holders of passports from the following countries need a visa to CA4 countries no matter which other documents they hold:

Afghanistan, Algeria, Angola, Armenia, Bangladesh, Bosnia and Herzegovina, Botswana, Cameroon, China, Republic of the Congo, Democratic Republic of the Congo, Eritrea, Ethiopia, Ghana, Haiti, Indonesia, Iran, Iraq, Jordan, Kenya, Laos, Lebanon, Liberia, Libya, Mali, Mongolia, Mozambique, Nepal, Nigeria, North Korea, Oman, Pakistan, Palestine, Sierra Leone, Somalia, Sri Lanka, Sudan, Syria, Taiwan, Timor-Leste, Vietnam and Yemen

Answer (score 4):

Similar to the Schengen area, Guatemala, Honduras, El Salvador and Nicaragua are all in the [CA4](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_America-4_Border_Control_Agreement) agreement

This means that visas issued by one of the states are valid for all the 4 states, and the visa-required lists are the [same](https://www.minex.gob.gt/Visor_Pagina.aspx?PaginaID=22).

[This non-governmental site](https://visaguide.world/north-america-caribbean/honduras-visa/) seems to suggest that Schengen RP holders are visa-free regardless of nationality but I haven't been able to back this up with official sources

Comment: I tested this on the IATA travel centre, and your conclusion is incorrect. See my answer.